# view must be a callable or a list/tuple when using decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, typeerror

After I created a decorator to forbid a logged user to access the login page this error started to appear when I run the server:

```
  File "/home/user1/Dev/sites/pai/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user1/Dev/sites/pai/planeja_tere/publications/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name='login'),
  File "/home/user1/Dev/sites/pai/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 73, in _path
    raise TypeError('view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().')
TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('publications/', views.Publications, name='publications'),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name='register'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import CreateUserForm
from .decorators import unauthenticated_user
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'publications/home.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def Publications(request):
    return render(request, 'publications/publications.html')

def registerPage(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, user + ', sua conta foi criada com sucesso!')

            return redirect('login')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'publications/register.html', context)
@unauthenticated_user
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Usuário ou senha incorretos')
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'publications/login.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')
```

decorators.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I'm usin this crash course as source of help on creating login and register views:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBsc65jTKvw&list=PL-51WBLyFTg2vW-_6XBoUpE7vpmoR3ztO&index=15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorator needs return a function:

```py
def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func # <-- add
```